# Embedded WPF form not showing within Outlook form region

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have built an VSTO Outlook Add-in which creates customs emails based on some input events. The form region of these emails consist of an embedded WPF form which contains TextBoxes, ListBoxes, ListViews, buttons and things like that.

What happens is that sometimes the embedded WPF form is not displayed within the form region. I say "sometimes" because from my development machine under Visual Studio 2019 and .NET 4.5, it is always correctly rendered and displayed however if I create a new clean virtual machine (no Visual Studio 2019 installed on it), with only Outlook 2019 or 365 installed plus my add-in and .NET Framework, then WPF form is not shown (the form region appears empty/blank).

I have tried to compare differences between the development machine and the clean virtual machine to see if i need to install some type of complement in order to Outlook be able to render the WPF form but I am not be able to discover what is missed. I tried to install Visual Studio 2010 for Office runtime but even with that installed the form region containing the WPF form is not shown.

I don't know if maybe there is some Office key in the registry I must enable in order to make it work. Also I have taken a look at Outlook options to see if there are something to adjust but I haven't seen anything regarding to Outlook render engine.

I have not posted any piece of code here because I think it is not a code related issue since it is working perfectly in my development machine. I think it is something related to Outlook itself.

Any ideas on what can be happening?

Comment: "displayed within the email body" - do you mean you are trying to show your WPF form *inside* the message body? Or is it a separate window?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, I do, I mean to show WPF form inside the message body.

Comment: Firstly, I am not sure that is possible, and secondly, why would you want to do that instead of showing a side panel or a form region?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Sorry, I didn't explain well. Yes, It is a form region which contains an embedded WPF control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved, the problem was that in the deployed machine a key was missing under below path:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/FormRegions

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to modify the add-in installer to include all prerequisites and do the required windows registry modifications. See [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022) for basics.

As for the form regions, you may find all the required information in the [Specifying Form Regions in the Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/creating-form-regions/specifying-form-regions-in-the-windows-registry) article.